# How to get a href attribute value in xml content (atom feed)?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, atom-feed

I'm saving the content (atom feed / xml content) from a get request as `content = response.text` and the content looks like this:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">title-a</title>
    <subtitle type="text">content: application/abc</subtitle>
    <updated>2021-08-05T16:29:20.202Z</updated>
    <id>tag:tag-a,2021-08:27445852</id>
    <generator uri="uri-a" version="v-5.1.0.3846329218047">abc</generator>
    <author>
        <name>name-a</name>
        <email>email-a</email>
    </author>
    <link href="url-a" rel="self"/>
    <link href="url-b" rel="next"/>
    <link href="url-c" rel="previous"/>
</feed>
```

**How can I get the value "url-b" of the href attribute with rel="next" ?**

I tried it with the ElementTree module, for example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

response = requests.get("myurl", headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {my_access_token}"})
content = response.text

tree = ElementTree.fromstring(content)

tree.find('.//link[@rel="next"]')
// or
tree.find('./link').attrib['href']
```

but that didn't work.

I appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

If there is an easier, simpler solution (maybe feedparser) I welcome that too.

Comment: The main problem is that you are not taking XML namespaces into account. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the value "url-b" of the href attribute with rel="next" ?

see below

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">title-a</title>
    <subtitle type="text">content: application/abc</subtitle>
    <updated>2021-08-05T16:29:20.202Z</updated>
    <id>tag:tag-a,2021-08:27445852</id>
    <generator uri="uri-a" version="v-5.1.0.3846329218047">abc</generator>
    <author>
        <name>name-a</name>
        <email>email-a</email>
    </author>
    <link href="url-a" rel="self"/>
    <link href="url-b" rel="next"/>
    <link href="url-c" rel="previous"/>
</feed>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
links = root.findall('.//{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link[@rel="next"]')
for link in links:
    print(f'{link.attrib["href"]}')
```

output

```
url-b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
./*[local-name()="feed"]/*[local-name()="link" and @rel="next"]/@href
```

This should result in "url-b".

Comment: Can you tell me how to write it exactly? I tried `tree.find('/*[local-name()='feed']/*[local-name()='link' and @rel='next']/@href')` and without strings `tree.find(/*[local-name()='feed']/*[local-name()='link' and @rel='next']/@href)`. Both is giving me a snytax error.

Comment: I changed my answer. You have to know that `'` quotes and `"` have to be used alternatively. This means that there is a rule for using them like this: `'`X`"`Y`'`Z`"`abc`"`Z`'`Y`"`X`'` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I tried the new expression `tree.find('/*[local-name()="feed"]/*[local-name()="link" and @rel="next"]/@href')` but I'm getting `KeyError: ('./*[local-name()="feed"]/*[local-name()="link" and @rel="next"]/@href',)` and `SyntaxError: invalid predicate`. Also a warning saying I should add a `.` at the beginning of the expression. I did that but still the same errors. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: The OP is using ElementTree, but this answer is for lxml.

Comment: I managed to get the result by using lxml.etree instead of ElementTree and the following expression `tree.xpath('//*[local-name()="feed"]/*[local-name()="link" and @rel="next"]/@href')`. But since I mentioned ElementTree in my question I will mark the other answer as complete.